# If the limit of $f$ and $g$ is different from zero, can the limit of $fg$ be zero?

Tags: limits, functions

Suppose:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)g(x)=0,$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)\ne0.$$

Is it has to be that
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0?$$

(Assume that the limits of $f$ and $g$ does not have to exist).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

You first write that $\lim g(x)\ne 0$. In that case,
$$ \lim f(x)=\lim\frac{f(x)g(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{\lim f(x)g(x)}{\lim g(x)}=0.$$
Later you write about a more general case, namely that the limit of $g(x)$ may not even exist. In that case, the limit of $f(x)$ need not exist either. As a simple example, consider
$$ f(x)=\begin{cases}1&x\in\Bbb Q\\0&x\notin\Bbb Q\end{cases}\qquad g(x)=1-f(x)$$

Comment: thats a great answer! thank you very much